# Yocto Bitbake Glibc build fails

Tags: linux, glibc, yocto, bitbake, microchip

I'm trying to build a Yocto image but the build fails when compiling glibc.

If I run just

```
bitbake glibc -c compile
```

I get a compilation error as follows:

```
/usr/src/debug/glibc/2.27-r0/git/nptl/pthread_atfork.c:51: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
| /media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/ld: /media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/rt/librt.so: hidden symbol `__dso_handle' isn't defined
| /media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi.gcc-cross-initial-arm/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/7.3.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| ../Makerules:599: recipe for target '/media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/rt/librt.so' failed
| make[2]: *** [/media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/build-arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/rt/librt.so] Error 1
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/git/rt'
| Makefile:235: recipe for target 'rt/others' failed
| make[1]: *** [rt/others] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/git'
| Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/build-microchip/tmp/work/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc/2.27-r0/temp/log.do_compile.31096)
ERROR: Task (/media/g/01D476BE2E4F26B0/AT91/SAMA5D27_SOM1/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.27.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 227 tasks of which 226 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

The glibc library is obviously very important so how can I resolved the compilation error?

Answer (score 4):

Get the packages.

```
 MACHINE=at91sam9rlek bitbake glibc
```

Clean

```
  MACHINE=at91sam9rlek bitbake -c clean glibc
```

Compile the recipe

```
  MACHINE=at91sam9rlek bitbake -f -c compile glibc
```

You can also specify the `MACHINE` definition. As I see, you use `meta-atmel`. You can set the `MACHINE` definition to according to your board.

**Note:** Be sure that your `meta-atmel` version matches with open-embedded and yocto poky version. It can be the root cause. Please, share the results.

Comment: The machine is set to _sama5d27-som1-ek-sd_ in local.conf and I tried a forced compile as above using:

`MACHINE=sama5d27-som1-ek-sd bitbake -f -c compile glibc`

but this still produced the same error. The versions seem to be the same, I'm following the tutorial here: https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the rocko verison of meta-atmel to yocto folder and I just compiled glibc recipe successfully with the following commnad.

```
MACHINE=sama5d27-som1-ek-sd bitbake -f -c compile glibc
Parsing recipes: 100% |######################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:01:17
Parsing of 2430 .bb files complete (0 cached, 2430 parsed). 3275 targets, 372 skipped, 37 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "sama5d27-som1-ek-sd"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2.4.3"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard cortexa5"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "rocko:05711ba18587aaaf4a9c465a1dd4537f27ceda93"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "rocko:eae996301d9c097bcbeb8046f08041dc82bb62f8"
meta-raspberrypi     = "rocko:8e4c537d84fdde8e3b4642d0dda2c0f4af76d52f"
meta-ti              = "rocko:8ba46625b0630b738724e6697fd3520116b082ef"
meta-freescale       = "rocko:61ab34ac6d664a229847b796ec20fd9f7c8ecbf4"
meta-qt5             = "rocko:682ad61c071a9710e9f9d8a32ab1b5f3c14953d1"
meta-solidrun-arm-imx6 = "rocko:d567d75be8984bd868df9af6108f12fecb049c2d"
meta-atmel           = "rocko:f71ed8ade26b4f26f00b624bf1b6fdc6e6c4aaf0"

NOTE: Tainting hash to force rebuild of task /home/eren/poky-rocko/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.26.bb, do_compile                                                                         | ETA:  0:00:00
WARNING: /home/eren/poky-rocko/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.26.bb.do_compile is tainted from a forced run                                                                                 | ETA:  0:00:00
Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 219 tasks of which 187 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown
```

I think you problem is, your build environment is not clean or you do not use the same version of meta-atmel, open-embedded and poky or any depended meta.

Comment: I think you're right as I have done this successfully on a VM, I have just been given a freshly installed Ubuntu laptop which I've moved development onto. Is there anything that can be checked or re-installed related to the above?

Comment: You just need to be careful of using the same yocto-meta version and use the  stable of community support level of yocto.

Comment: I tried the build again but this time using rocko version instead of sumo and everything worked perfectly. Seems this may be a Microchip issue with compatibility then. Thanks for your help, using rocko will work fine for what I need.

Comment: Your welcome. I always try to use the community version of yocto or at least the closest stable version of yocto. The possibility of Having trouble is more less

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by running the build on an ext4 filesystem. I don't know why, but building glibc on an NTFS filesystem seems to cause the problem.

check out details of the original problem's question and its solution answer:

https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/Yocto-Bitbake-Glibc-build-fails/m-p/1433766/highlight/true#M188597