# glibc is failing while doing bitbake[SUMO version]

Tags: linux, yocto, glibc, bitbake

I'm trying to build a Yocto image using the sumo version everything seems fine but while compiling glibc 2.27 it's failing and throwing the below error.

```
| /media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/build-i586-poky-linux/nptl/libpthread_pic.a(old_pthread_atfork.os): In function `__dyn_pthread_atfork':
| /usr/src/debug/glibc/2.27-r0/git/nptl/pthread_atfork.c:51: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
| /media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux.gcc-cross-initial-i586/../../libexec/i586-poky-linux.gcc-cross-initial-i586/gcc/i586-poky-linux/7.3.0/ld: /media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/build-i586-poky-linux/nptl/libpthread_pic.a(old_pthread_atfork.os): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
| /media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux.gcc-cross-initial-i586/../../libexec/i586-poky-linux.gcc-cross-initial-i586/gcc/i586-poky-linux/7.3.0/ld: final link failed: Bad value
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| ../Makerules:599: recipe for target '/media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/build-i586-poky-linux/nptl/libpthread.so' failed
| make[2]: *** [/media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/build-i586-poky-linux/nptl/libpthread.so] Error 1
| make[2]: Ledatag directory '/media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/git/nptl'
| Makefile:235: recipe for target 'nptl/others' failed
| make[1]: *** [nptl/others] Error 2
| make[1]: Ledatag directory '/media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/git'
| Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /media/data/68DC2D4CDC2D163A/data_Build/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/glibc/2.27-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6080)
```

I checked the 
[following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426734/yocto-bitbake-glibc-build-fails) question but it's not working. I tried in Ubuntu in both ubuntu 16 and 18.Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error message when building for raspberry pi on an external drive. Managed to get around it by doing a clean build on my host's SSD and made sure I used **bash** instead of **dash** with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Choose **No** to dash when prompted. Also might be worth it to make sure you do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install all of the Yocto required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
     build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \
     xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping python3-git python3-jinja2 libegl1-mesa libsdl1.2-dev \
     pylint3 xterm
```